# getting adaptive-wrap-prefix-mode to fill with spaces

Tags: adaptive-fill-mode

Hi I'm working on some assembly language files.

Here is a relevant snippet

```
            // Wait for line $ff and prepare next frame 
loop2:      lda #$ff                            // <- Inside the scope labels can collide so we use 'loop2' 
            cmp $d012
            bne loop2
```

What I'd like is for the comments to wrap where they are. i.e. a comment should wrap and be indented where the original comment began.

This should in theory be possible with `visual-fill-column-mode` and `adaptive-wrap-prefix-mode` - it should just be a matter of setting `adaptive-fill-regexp` to `.*//` and [according to the documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Adaptive-Fill.html):

> the candidate must match this regular expression, or match comment-start-skip. If it doesn’t, fill-context-prefix replaces the candidate with a string of spaces of the same width as it.

So I should get a string of spaces to give me an indent to match the original comment start.

Instead however I get this:

```
            // Wait for line $ff and prepare next frame 
loop2:      lda #$ff                            // <- Inside the scope labels can
loop2:      lda #$ff                              //collide so we use 'loop2'   
            cmp $d012
            bne loop2
```

Which is what you'd expect if the space-filling logic described in the doc wasn't working.

I've even tracked down the code in emacs (`fill.el.gz`), and it seems like it should do what I expect, but I don't have the knowhow at this point in time to actually debug it myself.

```lisp
;; If first-line-prefix comes from the first line,
;; see if it seems reasonable to use for all lines.
;; If not, replace it with whitespace.
(if (or (and first-line-regexp
             (string-match first-line-regexp
                           first-line-prefix))
        (and comment-start-skip
             (string-match comment-start-skip
                           first-line-prefix)))
    first-line-prefix
  (make-string (string-width first-line-prefix) ?\s))
```

anyone any idea what I could be doing wrong?

Comment: I don't know what's wrong, but if you `M-x edebug-defun` with your cursor on that function in `fill.el`, and then reproduce the bug, you'll land in that function and be able to step through it (in spacemacs, keep hitting `s`, in vanilla emacs I think it's `SPC`)